# Loop some data in MySQL to Create view

Tags: mysql

Example, i have a database, in database, have table `name` is UNIQUE :

```
|======|========|
| Name | Action |
|======|========|
| Jhon |   2    |
| Steve|   1    |
|======|========|
```

i want to CREATE VIEW in MySQL and i want VIEW like this:

```
|======|===========|
| Name | In Cation |
|======|===========|
| Jhon |   1 - 2   |
| Jhon |   2 - 2   |
| Steve|   1 - 1   |
|======|===========|
```

> The logic is, Jhon have 1-2 and 2-2 because in real table, jhon have 2
>   in action column, and Steve have only 1-1 because in real table, steve
>   have only 1 in Action colmn, i think that is possible because using
>   only loop, if Jhon have have 6 action, than jhon have 1-6, 2-6, 3-6 .... 6-6.

How do that?

Comment: @Pang, that it.., you can help this one?

Comment: Thanks for respect @Pang, that its... you can do that? :)

Comment: @pang , YES!, that RIGHT

Comment: @Pang, already.., you can check out now.., i don't realy understand about loop in MySQL

Comment: can you share your database structure??

Comment: @Pang, do not worry, that just example, that is UNIQUE / PRIMARY

Comment: @Pang, done, you can checkout.. please give me answer, thank you..

Comment: @chiragsatapara, i can't to share my true structure, i'am sorry about that but, if you familiar in MySQL i think you can to answer that :), thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are attempting to generate many rows from 1. Here I am using a helper table (dates) to do so.Note the use of a right outer join.

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t (name varchar(3),action int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values ('aaa',2),('bbb',1),('ccc',6);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select d.id from dates d limit 10;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
|    9 |
|   10 |
+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop view if exists v1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create view v1 (name , action ) as
    -> select t.name tname,concat(d.id ,' - ', t.action)  taction
    -> from t
    -> right outer join dates d on d.id <= t.action
    -> where t.name is not null
    -> order by t.name,d.id;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from v1;
+------+--------+
| name | action |
+------+--------+
| aaa  | 1 - 2  |
| aaa  | 2 - 2  |
| bbb  | 1 - 1  |
| ccc  | 1 - 6  |
| ccc  | 2 - 6  |
| ccc  | 3 - 6  |
| ccc  | 4 - 6  |
| ccc  | 5 - 6  |
| ccc  | 6 - 6  |
+------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```